# InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "{'url':

Tags: python, api, python-requests, pagination

I am trying to do pagination using pyspark and getting below error. My pagination link is in the header as Key [Link] and value [rel="next"]. The error is displayed at this line r1 = requests.get(response.links['next']).The issue is baseURL missing from the "next" URL being passed.

```
getURL = 'https://api.xxx.com/v3/direct-access/abc'
baseURL = 'https://api.xxx.com/v3/direct-access'
headers = {
"accept" : "application/json",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Bearer " + str(token)
 }
results = []

response = requests.get(getURL, headers=headers)
r = response.json()  

for i in r:  
results.append(i) 

while response.links['next']: ## != response.links['last']:  
r1 = requests.get(response.links['next'])  
r = r1.json()  
for i in r:  
    results.append(i)
 
Error: InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "{'url': '/abc?  action=next&next_page=%28id%2Ccompletionid%29+%3C+%28840430000754002%2C840430413029241%29&pagesize=10000', 'rel': 'next'}"
   InvalidSchema Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-45- 
   f27cc7bf373e> in <module> 17 18 
   while response.links['next']: ## != response.links['last']: ---> 19 
   r1 = requests.get(response.links['next']) 
   20 r = r1.json() 
    21 for i in r: 
   InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "{'url': 
   '/liners? 
   action=next&next_page=linerid+%3C+1010031264&pagesize=10000', 'rel': 
   'next'}"
```

How can i merge both baseURL and url into one link and pass it in while loop? Something like below

```
https://api.xxx.com/v3/direct-access/abc?action=next&next_page=%28id%2Ccompletionid%29+%3C+%28840430000754002%2C840430413029241%29&pagesize=10000

response = requests.get(getURL, headers=headers)
r = response.json()

for i in r:
results.append(i)

while response.links.get('next'):
   response = requests.get(baseURL + response.links['next'] 
                                  ['url'],headers=headers)
   r1 = response.json()
   for i in response:
     results.append(i)
```

#######below not returning results, running for ever ######

```
return results
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize((results))
print(rdd)
df = spark.read.option('multiline','true').json(rdd)
df.repartition(1).write.json(stagingpath,mode="overwrite")
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251600/discussion-between-arun-k-and-aaron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. `response.links['next']` is a dict `{'url': ...}`. `requests.get(...)` expects a URL.

```py
# requests.get(response.links['next'])
requests.get(response.links['next']['url'])
# requests.get(baseURL + response.links['next']['url'])  # With baseURL
```

2. `headers` are not passed in the subsequent calls.

```py
# requests.get(response.links['next']['url'])
requests.get(response.links['next']['url'], headers=headers)
```

3. `response` is not modified, resulting in infinite loop.

```py
while response.links['next']:
    # r1 = requests.get(response.links['next']['url'], headers=headers)
    response = requests.get(response.links['next']['url'], headers=headers)
```

4. For the last link, `'next'` will not exist.

```py
# while response.links['next']:
while response.links.get('next'):
```

---

Minimal, reproducible example:

```py
import requests

getURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/acjh/repos'
baseURL = ''
headers = {}
results = []

response = requests.get(getURL, headers=headers)
r = response.json()

for i in r:
    results.append(i)

while response.links.get('next'):
    nextURL = baseURL + response.links['next']['url']
    response = requests.get(nextURL, headers=headers)
    r = response.json()
    for i in r:
        results.append(i)

assert len(results) == requests.get(getURL[:-6]).json()['public_repos']
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
while response.links['next']:
    next_link = response.links['next']['url']
    r1 = requests.get(baseURL + next_link, headers=headers)
    r = r1.json()
    for i in r:
        results.append(i)
```

Comment: The code is not throwing error but its running for over 1.5 hrs and still not giving any output for print(results) or not even writing output to a path after sparkContext.parallelize((results)). How do i know whether a json output is getting written to results []

Comment: try use debugging line by line and see.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up the process like commit periodically from results[] to a folder path or paginate in chunks instead of going one by one, do 100 pages at a time.